# my serial port did not show my sensor data properly

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Hey i got a bit problem with my Arduino and sensor

Here is what i tried ;

```cpp
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true    // Set-up low-level interrupts for most acurate BPM math.
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground Library.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial blue(0,1);
const int PulseWire = 0;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 0
const int LED13 = 13;          // The on-board Arduino LED, close to PIN 13.
int Threshold = 550; 

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  blue.begin(9600);

  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);   
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED13);       //auto-magically blink Arduino's LED with heartbeat.
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);
  pulseSensor.begin();
}

void loop() {
  
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();
if(myBPM>200){
  myBPM-100;
  }
if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {
  Serial.println(myBPM);
  blue.println(myBPM);
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

this code I got from the example library and modified it.

so i want to send data to my android using Bluetooth but this sensor kinda ticked me off because whenever i use it with my HC-06 Bluetooth module it suddenly got a hearth beat without i even touching it and it just sends so much data ignoring the delay I set.
I just need to slowly sending data just like a second but the data didn't show up
so anyone can help?

Comment: Why did you put software serial on hardware serial pins? And delay of 10 ms only makes it send slower than 100 times per second.

Comment: this one also send to my android phone

Answer (score -1):

I read your code and I noticed this piece of code
`if(myBPM > 200){ myBPM - 100; }`
that is poorly written if (I understand correctly) you want to check the size of `myBPM` and if it is larger than 200 then it should be subtracted 100.
it should be:
`myBPM = myBPM - 100;` not `myBPM - 100;`
I hope my answer will help you. Have a nice day!

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the problem he described.

Comment: mo that one just me forget to erase sorry